# Linq GroupBy query not working with EF Core InMemory Database

Tags: linq, unit-testing, .net-core, group-by, in-memory-database

I am testing my .Net7 Web API repository with an InMemoryDB. The query compiles and works with actual DB but does not work when testing with InMemoryDB.

Package Version of the Repository Project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="7.0.0" />
```

Error Message When Running the Test:

```
 Error Message:
   System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TestSession>()
    .GroupBy(t => t.DutModel)' could not be translated. Additional information: A 'GroupBy' operation which is not composed into aggregate or projection of elements is not supported. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
  Stack Trace:
```

The Test Class looks like this: I am using xUnit Collection Feature to get a single Test DB instance.

```
[Collection("Database collection")]
class RepoTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test12322()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repo = new SessionRepository(_fixture.DbContext);
        var sessionParams = new SessionParams();

        // Act
        var dutModelGroup = await repo.Test(sessionParams);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(0, dutModelGroup.Count);
    }
}
```

The Repository Class is as below

This Implementation of the Test Method fails the test.
This exact methods works with actual SQL Database

```
class SessionRepo 
{
    public async Task<dynamic> Test(SessionParams sessionParams)
    {
        var result = await _context
                            .TestSessions
                            .GroupBy(s => s.DutModel)
                            .ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
}
```

This Implementation of the Test Method passes the test.

```
class SessionRepo 
{
  public async Task<dynamic> Test(SessionParams sessionParams)
     {
        var result = await _context
                            .TestSessions
                            .ToListAsync();

        return result.GroupBy(s => s.DutModel).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Second one is the right approach for such grouping. Groping without aggregation has no sense for SQL Server.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for the info. I was wondering why it was actually failing on the InMemoryDB test.

Comment: Probably because EF Core team has no time to update this provider. Better to use SQLite InMemory for such tests.

Comment: Tried with SQLite InMemoryDB and it's working now. Thanks for the suggestion @SvyatoslavDanyliv.